# Table Row Bottom Border "buckling" at certain window sizes

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple table to display information and wanted a border at the bottom of each row. I collapsed the borders to remove the space between the rows as to avoid the doubling of borders. And it works fine but when I adjust the screen size sometimes the border seems to break or buckle where it gets displaced slightly. I'm attaching an image of the phenomenon.

[image]

Here is the whole table as well:

[image]

And here is my CSS:

```
  table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody{
  width: 100% !important;
}

th{
  width: 8%;
  padding-left: 4%;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

td{
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

td ul {
  width: 90%;
}

td ul li {
  padding-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

tr{
  border-bottom: solid 1px black !important;
}
```

Is there any way around this? Or is it more a matter of my content?

Comment: We'll probably need to see some code that reproduces the issue. Can you make a Codepen or some other demo?

Comment: I wonder if you even need to collapse the borders since you only have border bottom on the `tr`s

Comment: @denmch heres the codepen: https://codepen.io/macro6461/pen/ZvVYeO

Comment: @Huangism I tried excluding the border-collapse attribute but then no borders show up at all :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table row borders work only as a side-effect of conflict-resolution in the [border-collapse algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-tables-3/#border-collapsing). A table row is not meant to have borders, but since the style is applied, and borders are collapsed, the browser attempts to resolve any potentially conflicting styles by applying border styles of the parent to the respective cells it houses.

What's actually being rendered is a series of cells of slightly varying height, each with its own bottom border resolved from the value taken from the parent `tr` element.

One alternative might be to wrap the first row with a `thead` element and each successive row with a `tbody` element, and then set them to `display: block` with `border-bottom`.

You can work out some different solutions, but the main issue here is just a misunderstanding of how borders work on table elements, and the W3C link should help to sort that out.

At small sizes this table becomes impossible to read, so I'd also recommend that you read [Richard Rutter on designing tables to be read](http://alistapart.com/article/web-typography-tables), and also avoid using percentage and viewport-based units for font-size and padding.

Comment: Thanks @denmch! I'll give it a try. As for the styling it will have a different layout on tablet/mobile that will be much more readable!